# 'Smtp' is ambiguous in the namespace 'MailBee.SmtpMail'

Tags: .net, vb.net, email

We are using MailBee for the first time but get this error:

```
'Smtp' is ambiguous in the namespace 'MailBee.SmtpMail'.
```

What does it mean and how can we create the objSMTP object?

Here is what the complete coding looks like:

```
Imports MailBee
Imports MailBee.DnsMX
Imports MailBee.Mime
Imports MailBee.SmtpMail
Imports MailBee.Pop3Mail
Imports MailBee.ImapMail
Imports MailBee.Security
Imports MailBee.AntiSpam
Imports MailBee.Outlook
Imports MailBee.Pdf

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim objSMTP As New Smtp

        objSMTP = CreateObject("MailBee.SMTP")

        ' Enable logging SMTP session into a file
        objSMTP.EnableLogging = True
        objSMTP.LogFilePath = "C:\emad.txt"
        objSMTP.ClearLog()

        objSMTP.LicenseKey = "This part is hidden"

        ' Set SMTP server name
        objSMTP.ServerName = "mail.bluebottle.com"

        ' Enable SMTP authentication
        objSMTP.AuthMethod = 2

        ' Set authentication credentials
        objSMTP.UserName = "This part is hidden"
        objSMTP.Password = "secret"

        ' Set message properties
        objSMTP.FromAddr = "This part is hidden"
        objSMTP.ToAddr = "someone@gmail.com"
        objSMTP.Subject = "Test"
        objSMTP.BodyText = "Body of the test message"

        ' Try to send message
        If objSMTP.Send Then
            MsgBox("Sent successfully")
        Else
            MsgBox("Error #" & objSMTP.ErrCode & ", " & objSMTP.ErrDesc)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

The line that has the error is the dim statement line.

Comment: It means that there is something wrong with `Dim objSMTP As New Smtp`, and it can't figure out which one you mean to use. Check to make sure that the object you're wanting to create is really called just `MailBee.Smtp` in the assembly and that there's not an `Smtp` in more than one assembly. (It also helps if you indicate which line caused the error; Visual Studio gives you that information.)

Comment: sometime this occurs when there are serveral namespaces with the same objets names, try to put the complete reference with the namespace instead of the single class.

Comment: Remove from the Imports all the lines except `Imports MailBee` and `Imports MailBee.SmtpMail`, then try again your code. Please remove also the `objSMTP = CreateObject("MailBee.SMTP")` line. It is not needed, you have just created the objSMTP at the previous line.

Comment: I tried to re-install the software and I do think there was too many copies of the assembly installed but I don't know how to check the assemblies. Anyway the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Dim objSMTP As New MailBee.Smtp
```

And at the same time, this is not needed:

```
    objSMTP = CreateObject("MailBee.SMTP")
```

It does the same thing as the New MailBee.Smtp line

Comment: I removed the objSMTP = CreateObject("MailBee.SMTP") line and used Dim objSMTP As New MailBee.Smtp but it states that type MailBee.Smtp is undefined. I think I will try to uninstall and re-install MailBee ans see what happens.

Comment: Then by looking at the includes you were showing, I would try:    Dim objSMTP As New MailBee.SmtpMail.Smtp.  Use your intellisense to find the proper full namespace.